# Django nested transactions and exceptions

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

For simplicity I have a nested atomic transaction in my code, basically if adding people to the movie fails (see first for loop) I'd like to display an exception specifically saying that this action failed and also roll back `movie.save()`, same for studios (see second for loop). But for some reason when either one fails `movie.save()` doesn't roll back, I get a movie saved in my database without any people or studios attached to it.

```
people = ['Mark', 'John', 'Mark']
studios = ['Universal Studios', 'Longcross Studios']

try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        movie = Movie(title=title, description=summary, pub_date=pub_date)
        movie.save()

        # iterate through people list, get the pk from database and add it to the movie
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                for p in people:
                    person = Person.objects.get(name=p)
                    movie.people.add(person)

        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR('One or more performers from %s does not '
                                               'exist in database, please add them and '
                                               'rerun the command.' % str(people)))
            continue

        # iterate through studio list, get the pk from database and add it to the movie
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                for s in studios:
                    studio = Studio.objects.get(name=s)
                    movie.studios.add(studio)
        except Studio.DoesNotExist:
            self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR('One or more studios from %s does not '
                                               'exist in database, please add them and '
                                               'rerun the command.' % str(studios)))
            continue

        movie.save()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.NOTICE('Successfully added movie %s' % title))

except Exception as e:
    self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR('Failed to add movie to the database.'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rollback happens when an `atomic` block is exited by an exception. But you're catching the exceptions and suppressing them, so rollback doesn't happen. To let the exception propagate after logging the message you need to use `raise`, not `continue`.

Comment: A bit old answer, but I just want to say that this is bad practice: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly

Comment: @SimeonAleksov: What exactly do you think is bad practice? If you mean suppressing exceptions inside atomic blocks, that's not what's happening here. The OP just wants to print an error message before raising the exception.

Comment: @SimeonAleksov I was questioning this myself... The Django docs as you point out do say exceptions should not be caught within an atomic block, but I think that is an overgeneralization. 
Some exceptions clearly break the current transaction (e.g. DatabaseError and it's subclasses), but ObjectDoesNotExist is just an informational error - whether or not it should rollback depends on your code. A very common pattern is to catch ObjectDoesNotExist rather than use `query.exists()` as it's neater and slightly more performant - you'll see that used in the Django source itself.